# Outlook needs password

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, passwords, microsoft-account

I have a problem similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1349327/outlook-needs-password-but-dialog-box-disappears), but there are additional symptoms, and solutions proposed there did not work. On Windows 10 [b10.0.19043.1165], I have two email accounts configured in Outlook 2016 Pro Plus [v2107 b14228.20226 Klick-und-Los]:

- when starting Outlook, a window pops up asking for a password for a second email account; since the password for this account does not work, I need to click this window away *(in the linked-to question,
  this was not mentioned)*: 
   [image: Screenshot1]

  - Outlook starts normally and the first account works normally, but when navigating to the second account, I see the following message in the Taskbar: 
     [image: Screenshot2]
  - To sync, I need to either click directly on the Taskbar message or on *Type Exchange Password & Connect* within Outlook; afterwards, the message in the Taskbar, Outlook is able to sync and there was _o need to type the password manually

These did not give resolve the issue:

- starting Outlook in Safe Mode and enter the IDs if asked: `Outlook.exe /safe`
- disabling Modern Authentication in the Registry by creating DWORDs `EnableADAL` [value `0`] and `DisableADALatopWAMOverride` [value `1`] within Registry key:

  ```
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\
  ```
- updating the password in *Credential Manager* [German: Anmeldeinformationsverwaltung]
- running MS Office Repair
- generating a new Outlook profile with only the non-working email account and the same behaviour occurred

It seems Outlook wants to link to some Microsoft account using the same e-mail address as a login *(Windows login uses a local account, which is not linked to a Microsoft account)* and wants to force me to connect to it

- I do have an email account with the username as the existing local account, and if I input the Microsoft passphrase in the first screenshot, it asks me if I want to sync my Apps and offers help in storing my passwords, both of which I do not want

Any ideas?

Comment: You unlink the Microsoft Account from Outlook by removing the profile within Outlook.  Likewise, Credential Manager, is easy enough to run (just search for it in the start menu).  What does your IT Administrator have to say about this problem?

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for your notes. I've eddited my question, to explain why I could not follow the other two explainations.     About the IT administrator: As this is a family business PC, basically the IT administrator is currently typing this message :-)

Comment: @BerndGit I'm confused as to what you want: if you want to remove the second account from Outlook, delete it via _File_ → _Account Information_ → _Account Settings_ → _Account Settings_ → _Email_ → Highlight email account → _Remove_ | you may also need to delete the account from the UWP Mail app.

Comment: @JW0914: issue solved already. See answer of Christy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you didn't enter your password within the pop-up box in Step 2 and the account works normally after you enter your password, right? If so, what's that account?

If you are setting up a non-Office365 mailbox or an on-premises Exchange mailbox, it's recommended to modify the below Registry key to see if there are any differences:

1. Open Registry Editor and go to:

   ```
   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
   ```
2. Create a DWORD [30bit] `ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint` with a value of `1` to enable it

   - If you modify the Registry by mistake, serious problems may occur, so lease [back up](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) the Registry before doing so

Comment: Thank you Christy.  That solved the problem. First login window does not appear any more. Outlook directly connects to server.  Happy that issue is solved. Extra reward of will be +50 given in ~24 hrs.

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think I may be able to help.

"Einstellungen für Benutzerkontensteuerung" = User account Control.
Your looking for something similar to this "Qualifikationsmanager."

This has led me in no cruel way to believe that German is not your native language and you should be looking into changing over to your native language pack on your system to make helping you easier.

It seems you may need to run a full office repair to fix this.  It is usually not the account or outlook's fault but the credentials might be corrupt and a full repair will help with this.  first i would unlink all accounts even the ones you are sure should be there then I would full repair to force the system to fix possible errors.  in this case, a quick repair will not be enough.  Please translate specific parts before searching to the language on your system.

NOTES:  you should go to:  Control Panel, then Uninstall A Program, then go to Office ...rest of name..., choose Change at the top after making office blue and choose Repair then choose full repair.  should be very similar to that.  if you are uncomfortable please take your time and also feel free to ask any questions you may have:)

Comment: Thanks James. I found the Cedential Manager. It is called "Anmeldeinformationsverwaltung" seems that I'm not the only german speaking native who had problems in locating it. Other languages see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/4383152.   Working with CM, and Office repair didn't work. Kindly refer to my updated Post, where I have described further observations & interpretations.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but wonderful news!