# MS Outlook 365 flickering authentication box

Tags: office365

I have an End User (EU) who was migrated to MS Office 365. EU had a flickering authentication box when opening Outlook. In other Office applications, it shows EU needs to log back in then it shows account needs to be activated.

Solution in the following post worked for a while till EU got an update last week.
[Outlook needs password but dialog box disappears](https://superuser.com/questions/1349327/outlook-needs-password-but-dialog-box-disappears)

Since I tried to reapply that solution but same issue.
Is there a definite solution. I haven't rolled back the updates cause in a corporate environment and that would mean rolling individuals each time.

Comment: See if turning off Hardware Acceleration works. Any Office App, Advanced.  I am not having an issue here even though HA is ON.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the working solution at [Stephen Hackers Blog](https://www.stephenhackers.co.uk/outlook-credentials-flashing-and-closing-constantly/), so all credit goes to Stephen.

1. Close Outlook
2. Open Word > Create a blank document
3. File > Account > Sign Out

[image]

4. Then click sign in, Username and Password prompts. Log in and authenticate.
5. Close Word
6. Open Outlook and everything worked as normal.