# Outlook continually disconnects with "need password"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I'm running Office 365 on Windows and 3 days ago our mail-server underwent some work. Ever since, Outlook is almost always in a disconnected state:

[image][image]

[image]

Clicking either the *type Exchange password and connect* or the *need password* button will cause Outlook to briefly connect to the server just long enough to perform send/receive, then it will disconnect again after anything from a few seconds to a few minutes. At no point am I prompted to enter my password - I can see a popup flash for a fraction of a second but I can't see what it is before it disappears.

Outlook on another PC for the same account has no such problems which leads me to believe it's a local issue - did I forget to click "remember password?" But where can I look for any relevant settings and what might the problem/solution be?

Comment: Any updates on your issue? Have you resolved this issue? If your issue has been resolved yet, you could mark the helpful reply as best answer or share your method, your action will be helpful other people who encounter the same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook needs password but dialog box disappears](https://superuser.com/questions/1349327/outlook-needs-password-but-dialog-box-disappears)

Comment: What work was done on the Exchange server?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, here are some suggestions for your reference:

1. Recreate outlook profile and check if this issue continues.
2. Removing the credential from Windows Credentials and re-login the Outlook client

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Logging out and in again in Outlook solved this issue for me. Probably a cache issue.
File -> Office Account -> Sign out -> Sign in.

Removing the windows credentials, reinstalling office 365, or restarting the computer and logging into Windows again did not help.