# Outlook Exchange user login error

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

When I try to add an exchange account to Outlook, it grabs the mail, but when I enter the password, a popup opens up and then instantly closes multiple times, then after a couple of tries it throws an error.

The odd thing is, when I try the exact same thing on another Windows user, it works without a problem.

I've tried all of the steps here but to no avail.

[Outlook needs password but dialog box disappears](https://superuser.com/questions/1349327/outlook-needs-password-but-dialog-box-disappears)

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing issues adding an Exchange account to Outlook and have tried the solutions provided in the link you provided, here are some additional steps you can try:

1. Clear cached credentials: Go to Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager, and then select "Windows Credentials." Look for any cached credentials related to your Exchange account and remove them. Then, try adding the Exchange account again.
2. Disable antivirus software: Your antivirus software may be interfering with Outlook's ability to connect to the Exchange server. Try temporarily disabling your antivirus software and see if that resolves the issue.
3. Check for Windows updates: Make sure your Windows operating system is up to date. Go to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update, and then check for any available updates.
4. Create a new Windows user profile: If the issue persists, try creating a new Windows user profile and see if you can add the Exchange account from there.

Comment: Sadly the steps don't help.
It works in a new Windows user profile, but we have a ton of old certificates that can't be exported to the new user. A temporary solution is using 2 user accounts, but it isn't very user-friendly. Any other ideas?